# Calculating centroid of matrix with long/lat data

Tags: r, dataframe, latitude-longitude, centroid

I am trying to calculate the centroid of a dataframe containing the following long/lat data:

```
> test_points
     Lon    Lat
1  6.913 51.131
2  6.900 51.133
3  6.883 51.167
4  6.933 51.167
5  6.941 51.177
6  6.982 51.178
7  7.000 51.200
8  6.861 51.205
9  7.014 51.221
10 8.041 51.750
11 8.000 51.767
12 8.050 51.800
```

However when I apply the centroid function:

```
centroid(test_points)
```

I get the following result:

```
          lon      lat
[1,] 10.96005 53.32525
```

Does anybody have any idea where this goes wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: From which package does the `centroid` function come? Can you make this a reproducible example?

Comment: the ```geosphere``` package

Comment: How exactly do a make this a reproducible example? I've given you all the information I use

Comment: centroid of point is point, what does your data represent?

Comment: Each row in the dataframe represents a geographical point in Germany. I want to calculate the center of these 11 places, however, the centroid function, which has yielded right answers before, yields a clearly wrong answer here. My question is: what goes wrong?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example and https://reprex.tidyverse.org/ on how to make example reproducible. Problem here is that you did not provide data in a way people can easily use in their R session